# Form ActionResult is not being fired

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My form's `ActionResult` method is not properly being fired after the submit button is clicked. I've spent a few hours searching on the issue and can't find out why the `ActionResult` is not being fired.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model Azure.Models.UserModel

<form method="post">
    <div class="text-center">
        <br/>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
        {
            @: Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) <br /> <br />
            @: Note: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Note) <br /> <br />
            <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        }
    </div>
</form>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitForm(UserModel model)
        {
            String name = model.Name;
            String note = model.Note;

            //Insert into database

            return View(); 
        }
    }
```

I know this is probably very trivial but I can't find anything explaining why the event isn't being fired.

Comment: Just so you know; Controller methods in MVC are called Actions. ActionResult is the return type of the Action. Not all Actions necessarily have the return type of ActionResult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nesting a form within a form: the construct

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm()) { }
```

outputs both an opening and closing tag for a form element.

If you remove the form tags wrapping your using statement, you should find it works.

Comment: Wow... I feel like an idiot. Will accept the answer in 9 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Ha, no problem! It's a weird bit of syntax and always seems a bit hacky to me - it confused me when I first started using it.